# Motif programming and UTF-8

Tags: c, user-interface, text, character-encoding, motif

I'm new to Motif programming and I want to use UTF-8 encoding.

I've tried `XtSetLanguageProc (NULL, NULL, NULL);` but when I read a file in Motif (editor text-like in 6A volume motif programming), I've got problems with accented characters.

I had to use `setlocale()`?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Motif, you have to switch to the correct font for the languages that you are using. There is currently no single UTF-8 font that has full support for all languages.

If there is more to your problem you might want to ask it on MotifZone http://www.motifzone.com/forum/unicode-support since Motif is not a commonly used toolkit anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, you need a font that supports Unicode. The ones with most broad support are Iso10646 fonts. Assuming Linux with X11, launch `xfontsel` to find them. Select `iso10646` from the `rgstry` drop-down menu. Then `fmly` menu will list available fonts with that encoding. Some are very limited, but

```
-*-fixed-medium-*-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-*
```

is a good choice that comes with the X11 installation.

Then, you need either to set that font as a fallback in your Motif program or supply the resource via command-line

```
xmprogram -xrm '*fontList: -*-fixed-medium-*-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-*'
```

If all worked right, there will be no problems with accented characters anymore.

For a font supporting even more glyphs, consider [GNU Unifont](https://www.unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html).